# Animate a div down and up using Jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need help in animating a div up on click and down via the same click link. Here is my Javascript below:

```
 $(function() {

        // global functions
        var dash = $('#Dashboard');
        var dashBtn = $('#dashClick');
        var state = dash.css({
            "top":600
        });


        var clicked = dashBtn.click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          if(clicked) {
            dash.animate({"top":0});
          } 

          if(state > 0 && clicked) {
            dash.animate({"top":600});
          }
        });

        //make it height of document
        dash.height($(document).height()); 
    });
```

and my HtML below showing the references to the javascript with the ID's:

```
<a id="dashClick" href="#">Dashboard</a>
<div id="Dashboard"> 
          <h2 class="dashTitle">Project Information</h2>
          <div class="dashInnerAdd">
            <p>
       Project name: CSS3 Effects N' Stuff 
       My github is: https://github.com/Amechi101/css3effects
            </p> 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </main>  <!-- end grid main-->
    </div> 

   <!--end wrap -->
```

Comment: I think you can chain your calls to animate. Do you want to get it to go up then down when you click once? Or if you click it get it to animate one way, click again animate the other way.

You can use CSS transitions to do this and it may be easier. Simply add or remove the CSS class to animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main javascript only executes once. You need to track state from within the click handler. Try this:

```
$(function() {

    // global functions
    var dash = $('#Dashboard');
    var dashBtn = $('#dashClick');
    var state = true;


    dashBtn.click(function(e) {
      state = !state;
      e.preventDefault();

      if(state) {
        dash.animate({"top":20});
      } 

      if(!state) {
        dash.animate({"top":600});
      }
    });

    //make it height of document
    dash.height($(document).height()); 
});
```

Comment: much better, but this still doesn't do anything. see http://jsfiddle.net/Ug6GM/2/. I wouldn't mind hearing what else Amechi changed to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things (see the code for all changes):

If you want to use `top`, you probably are wanting it to behave like it does with absolute positioning. To do that, you need a container with relative positioning around the `#Dashboard`. Also, your javascript animate needs px values. `"top":600` should really be `top:"600px"`.

html:

```
<a id="dashClick" href="#">Dashboard</a>
<div class="container">
    <div id="Dashboard"> 
          <h2 class="dashTitle">Project Information</h2>
          <div class="dashInnerAdd">
            <p>
       Project name: CSS3 Effects N' Stuff 
       My github is: https://github.com/Amechi101/css3effects
            </p> 
          </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {

    // global functions
    var dash = $('#Dashboard');
    var dashBtn = $('#dashClick');
    var clicked = false;

    dashBtn.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if(clicked === true) {
        clicked = false;
        dash.animate({top:"0px"});
      } else {
        clicked = true;
        dash.animate({top:"600px"});
      }
    });

    //make it height of document
    dash.height($(document).height()); 
});
```

and some css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
#Dashboard {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SQK78/2/

If you *don't* need the absolute positioning, you can just change `top` to `marginTop`, and you can get rid of the `container` wrapper as well as all of the css in that fiddle.